# Integration of Excel With .Net

Tags: c#

HI All,

I want to export the excel file using c# and in excel it should have a ribbon (button in excel) called as refresh which will get the latest data from server.

Please let me know how to go forward..

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/hh133430.aspx). Visual Studio Tools for Office allows you to customize Office applications, using .Net. For Excel, you can customize specific documents or write add-ins, working from Visual Studio, in VB.Net or C#.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, After creating a ribbon using VSTO, is it possible to create the event in the excel which will refresh the data.

Comment: It should not be a problem. Your code in VSTO is .Net, so you should have no problem calling your server, and you have complete access to Excel via Interop. The VSTO dev center has a bunch of tutorial videos here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/dd164303.aspx
The 2 following demonstrate how to interact with a database, and how to write to a worksheet:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/cc337994.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/cc337989.aspx